# Bot was not started on DialogFlow for Telegram Integration

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram, telegram-bot

When I put the Telegram Token in DialogFlow, I get the error Bot was not started. I have started the bot in Telegram app. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let’s say we will make the bot to give answers about programming language

steps:

1. create new agent
2. create entities
3. create the words contained in the entities
4. create intents
5. enter training phases (DialogFlow will recognise parts of the phases containing entities you just created. it will give different colors for different entities)
6. set default responses
7. add google assistant (if needed)
8. add response for Google Assistant. activate Google Assistant Response. choose basic card. add the image link (we can do this later). put the search text

https://google.com/search?q=how+to+le...

9. add more responses (telegram, slack, web demo, twitter, facebook messenger, etc.). you will get a token for activating the integration (in this example) i use Telegram
10. add response to Telegram. add card. fill in the card. don’t forget to add the search terms (you can add image url later)
11. at action and parameters section, set prompts for responses if needed
12. go to integrations. choose telegram (or whatever you chose before)
13. follow the instructions on how to create a bot in a telegram here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/d...
14. copy the generated token
15. press start
16. there you go! now you have your own bot :)

Comment: Thanks @Jopapy19